# fnServerParams using DataTables and Perl CGI

Tags: jquery, perl, cgi, datatables

I got this CGI code here:

```
   \$('#example').dataTable( {
         "bProcessing": true,
         "bServerSide": true,
         "sAjaxSource": "scripts/run.cgi",
         "fnServerParams": function ( aoData ) {
            aoData.push( { "mysqltablename": "MYSQL_123490dfasdf039a" } );
         },
         "iDisplayLength": 50
     } );
```

I'm not understanding how to access the key:value (mysqltable,MYSQL_123490dfasdf039a) on the run.cgi side. I tried the following but don't see it listed. Help.

```
new CGI
...
my %paramstemp = $q->Vars;
       open (FILE, ">/proj/hwmodels/unix_webserver/temp/asdf") ;
       print FILE Dumper \%paramstemp; 
       close FILE;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

spent too many hours on this. Found out the syntax is exactly this:

```
                 "fnServerParams": function ( aoData ) {
                    aoData.push( { "name": "mysqltablename", "value": "MYSQL_123490dfasdf039a" }, { "name": "asdfasdf", "value": "asdfasdfasdf" } );
                 }
```